# select a tab by ID in Kango browser extension

Tags: browser-extension, kango-framework

I'm using the Kango framework to develop a browser extension. I open a new tab to let the user input some info. When they submit the form it closes the tab, but I want to select the tab they were previously viewing.

This is pretty trivial in Chrome and Firefox so I hope it's supported, but I can't find a method for it.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not mentioned in their online documentation, a quick read of the code revealed an activate() method on the KangoBrowserTab object. I haven't tested it on IE, but it works great on Chrome and FF.